# Free Tool to create Social Media Graphics for Websites and Landing Pages?

Tags: resource-recommendations, free, open-source

I am searching a free tool to create Landing Page Buttons, cool designs, social media call-to-action tools, graphics like below - for beginners. I have it difficult finding free tools. Could you recommend me a few and if you believe that one particular paid tool is really great, which one would be worth it?

Would like to create those things for my clients as an additional service!

[image]

OR

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Any graphics software will help you produce those. There will be a learning curve associated with them, but if you intend to keep working on these it's worth investing your time in it.

Free options are [The Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) and [**Inkscape**](http://www.inkscape.org/en/). Inkscape deals with vector graphics, so I'd definitely recommend it!

For paid options you have Photoshop (bitmap) and **Illustrator** (vector). They are both very powerful tools, and if you only want to design stuff like the images you posted it might be an overkill, at least to get you started. I'd give Inkscape a try and then see if you need to switch to a more complete solution like Illustrator.

Comment: do thise tools offer templates and prepared buttons/graphics? it`s because i might not be able to create things from scratch

Comment: No, they don't. But you can do a search for free vector resources, download them and paste them in there to play with them. Just make sure they are ok for commercial use. For example, you could check http://www.vecteezy.com/